# Get a document from MongoDB by matching keys and values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have mongodb schema like this:

```json
{
  "name": "some_name",
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3"
}
```

**Amount of key-values may be different in each document, they're not fixed. But field `name` is fixed and it's always on first position in every document.**

I need to find a document which matching all both keys and values, **BUT** if given key-values are matching **AND** there are more of them than in the schema, return matching document anyway.

Current state:
If im trying to use `find_one()` and passing `search fields` with different amount of key-values than in schema, it returns None.

Example of my code:

```py
search_fields = {
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3",
  "field4": "value4"
}
req.app.mongodb["forms"].find_one(search_fields) # None
```

I'm trying to find a document with name `some_name` with `search_fields` key-values but im getting `None` because in that document only **3 fields** presented but **4 given**.

**Amount of key-values in `search_fields` might be different.**

Answer (score 0):

Your search_fields must then include any combination of the three parameters, separated by an "$or" operator. Something like that:`search_fields = {"$or":[ {3 fields here}, {next 3 fields here}, ...]}`

Comment: Forgot to mention that amount of key values in `search_fields` might be different also.

Comment: I need to match key-values from `search_fields` with key-values in all documents and when first document with all matching key-values is found, return it. Doesn't matter how much fields was in `search_fields`

Comment: Or maybe if pymongo doesn't have that functionality for getting data like this,  should I just get all documents and find a document with all matching fields? I think it's wouldn't be a good solution.